# rake db:migrate not working, no errors

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rake, migrate

I'm trying to run rake db:migrate on a migration I made to drop a few columns and add a few others.
Here is the migration I'm trying to run:

```
     class Demographics < ActiveRecord::Migration
        def change
    change_table :demographics do |t|
    t.remove_column :demographics, :race
    t.remove_column :demographics, :other_race
    t.integer :race_id
    t.integer :other_race_id
    t.remove :demographics, :education
    t.integer :education_id

    t.remove :other_education
    t.integer :other_education_id

end
end
end
```

Here is the output of: rake db:migrate status --trace

```
    ** Invoke db:migrate (first_time)
    ** Invoke environment (first_time)
    ** Execute environment
    ** Invoke db:load_config (first_time)
    ** Execute db:load_config
    ** Execute db:migrate
    ** Invoke db:_dump (first_time)
    ** Execute db:_dump
    ** Invoke db:schema:dump (first_time)
    ** Invoke environment 
    ** Invoke db:load_config 
    ** Execute db:schema:dump
    rake aborted!
    Don't know how to build task 'status'
    /var/lib/gems/2.0.0/gems/rake-10.1.1/lib/rake/task_manager.rb:49:in `[]'
    /var/lib/gems/2.0.0/gems/rake-10.1.1/lib/rake/application.rb:148:in `invoke_task'
    /var/lib/gems/2.0.0/gems/rake-10.1.1/lib/rake/application.rb:106:in `block (2 levels) in top_level'
    /var/lib/gems/2.0.0/gems/rake-10.1.1/lib/rake/application.rb:106:in `each'
    /var/lib/gems/2.0.0/gems/rake-10.1.1/lib/rake/application.rb:106:in `block in top_level'
    /var/lib/gems/2.0.0/gems/rake-10.1.1/lib/rake/application.rb:115:in `run_with_threads'
    /var/lib/gems/2.0.0/gems/rake-10.1.1/lib/rake/application.rb:100:in `top_level'
    /var/lib/gems/2.0.0/gems/rake-10.1.1/lib/rake/application.rb:78:in `block in run'
    /var/lib/gems/2.0.0/gems/rake-10.1.1/lib/rake/application.rb:165:in `standard_exception_handling'
    /var/lib/gems/2.0.0/gems/rake-10.1.1/lib/rake/application.rb:75:in `run'
    /var/lib/gems/2.0.0/gems/rake-10.1.1/bin/rake:33:in `<top (required)>'
    /usr/local/bin/rake:23:in `load'
    /usr/local/bin/rake:23:in `<main>'`enter code here`
```

Comment: I experienced the same problem - I deleted the migration file, ran rake db:migrate - added migration again file and then ran again rake db:migrate

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need `status` in the migrate command:

`rake db:migrate`

should be enough.

You are actually getting an error from `rake` because of having status in the command:

```
rake aborted!
    Don't know how to build task 'status'
```

**EDIT**

Following our discussion I now understand more.

The migration `Demographics` has already been applied to the database in the past.  This is proved by its 14 digit datetime being included in the `schema_migrations` table.

Migrations are designed to be run once only.  They make a change to the database (schema and/or data) and you move on.

When you run `rake db:migrate` it finds any migration not yet applied to the database (in datetime order from the migration filename), applies it, then puts an entry for the datatime in `schema_migrations`.  Any migration which already has an entry in `schema_migrations` is ignored.

If you want to make a further change to the database - even to a table created in a previous migration - you should create a new migration, and then use `bin rake db:migrate` to apply it.

Yes you can backout a previously applied migration - `rake db:rollback`.  Rollbacks will apply in the reverse order the migrations were applied, ie. working backwards from the end of `schema_migrations`.  By default it will only back out the last migration, although you can use the `STEP` parameter to do more (`rake db:rollback STEP=3` for example).

You can also redo a previously applied migraton - `rake db:migrate:redo` - again with optional STEP parameter.  This is really just a shortcut for rollback followed by migrate.

**RECOMMENDATION**

My recommendation to you would be to put the `Demographics` migration file back to the way it was before you made the change.  This is important in case the migrations need to be all reapplied in the future.

I would now create a new migration to apply the changes to your table:

`rails generate migration UseForiegnKeysInDemographics`

Make the required alterations; you only need mention the changes to the table:

e.g.

```
class UseForiegnKeysInDemographics < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    remove_column :demographics, :race
    remove_column :demographics, :other_race
    remove_column :demographics, :education
    remove_column :demographics, :other_education

    add_column :demographics, :race_id,            :integer
    add_column :demographics, :other_race_id,      :integer
    add_column :demographics, :education_id,       :integer
    add_column :demographics, :other_education_id, :integer
  end
end
```

And apply this new migration:

`rake db:migrate`

I suggest you have a read of the Rails guide on migrations; http://guides.rubyonrails.org/migrations.html as it explains everything better than my brief summary.

**Footnote:**
As you want to add foreign keys to the demographics table, you might want to consider `add_reference` instead of `add_column`.  I didn't include this in my example above because I don't know the details of your other tables, but it's well documented in the Rails guide.

Comment: having 'status' in the command is the only way I get to see the error.  When I do 'rake db:migrate' it simply returns my prompt, but the db doesn't change. 'rake db:migrate --trace' dumps some unhelpful comments:  Invoke db:migrate (first_time) ** Invoke environment (first_time) ** Execute environment ** Invoke db:load_config (first_time) ** Execute db:load_config ** Execute db:migrate ** Invoke db:_dump (first_time) ** Execute db:_dump ** Invoke db:schema:dump (first_time) ** Invoke environment ** Invoke db:load_config ** Execute db:schema:dump

Comment: It actually looks like you are seeing nothing because there is nothing to see.  Is it possible this migration has already been loaded into the database?  Did you change it but didn't roll it back first?  Have a look in your `schema_migrations` table and see if there is already an entry for this migration.

Comment: I'm a rails newbie.  I checked the schema_migrations table and there are 18 rows in it.  Just a version column with numbers in it.  Is there a way to force queued migrations to execute?  Also, I looked in schema.rb, and my migration hasn't affected this file.  Thanks for your help!

Comment: The numbers in the version column correspond to the numbers which start the filename of each migration - actually it's just a datetime when the migration was created.  For this migration you are trying to load, look to the see if the 14 digit datetime string at the beginning of the filename is one of those in the `schema_migrations` table.  If it is then the migration has already been loaded which is why it does nothing when you try to load it again.

Comment: yes sir, the migration I'm using is in the list.  Is there some kind of rake db:doit command to get this migration activated?  What am I missing?  Thanks again.

Comment: I've updated my answer as I wanted to say more than I could in a comment ;)

Answer (score 1):

I see an issue with your command : `rake db:migrate status --trace`

You are trying to achieve two things with one command i.e., run the migrations as well as check the status of the migrations with the detailed steps performed.

### You can do it in two ways:

**1. First Way**

To perform the migrations use

`rake db:migrate --trace`

And then check the `status` of all your migrations within the application, use

`rake db:migrate:status`

**2. Alternatively**

`rake db:migrate db:migrate:status --trace`

You almost had that but `status` task is within `db:migrate` namespace so you need to use `db:migrate:status`.  Here, the first `db:migrate` will perform the pending migrations whereas `db:migrate:status` will give the status of all migrations and `--trace` will give you full backtrace.

Comment: rake db:migrate --trace:** Invoke db:migrate (first_time)
** Invoke environment (first_time)
** Execute environment
** Invoke db:load_config (first_time)
** Execute db:load_config
** Execute db:migrate
** Invoke db:_dump (first_time)
** Execute db:_dump
** Invoke db:schema:dump (first_time)
** Invoke environment 
** Invoke db:load_config 
** Execute db:schema:dump